# Unbounded sequence compared to $n$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

For an unbounded sequence $(a_{n})$, can $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_n}{n} = 0?$$

I'm assuming $n$ must be $>0$. There can be unbounded sequences with limits not infinity, and if $n \to \infty$ in the denominator, then there would be a limit of $0$.

But this is intuition, not proof.

Any suggestions?

Comment: $$a_n=(-1)^nn^2$$ 
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_n}{n} = ?$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unbounded sequences cannot have a finite limit.

If you set $a_n =\sqrt n$, then $(a_n)$ is unbounded, but
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}n= \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{\sqrt n} = 0.
$$
If $b_n = bn$, $b\in\mathbb R$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{b_n}n=b$.

Setting $c_n=n^2$ yields $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{c_n}n=+\infty$.

For $d_n=(-1)^nn$, the limit for $n\to \infty$ of $\frac{a_n}n$ does not exist.

In summary, everything can happen for the limit of $\frac{a_n}n$ for unbounded $(a_n)$.

Answer (score 1):

let $a_n=\ln(n)$, then the limit $\frac{lnn}{n}$ is $0$ by L'Hospital's rule. So if you want an unbounded sequence with limit not $\infty$, just set $b_n=\ln(n)$ for even $n$, and $b_n=1$ for odd $n$, then the limit of $b_n$ doesn't exist, and it also satisfies your requirement, i.e. $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{b_n}{n}=0$.

Comment: thanks, but I'm attempting to prove that an (unbounded sequence)/n can have a limit of 0 as n=> inf

Comment: @MathRaider If you want to prove an unbounded sequence can have limit $0$, want you need to do is to give an explicit example. But your statement is not true for a general unbounded sequence, for example $a_n=n$.